# IV curves of solar cells in parallel and series

Tags: voltage, current, solar-cell, iv-curve

When 2 solar cells are in parallel, is it that the final IV curve is the simple addition of Currents (for same voltage) of both individual IV curves ?
My main doubt is what happens in 2nd and 4th quadrant.
Also can you answer the same question for solar cells in series.
Assume that there are no bypass diodes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> When 2 solar cells are in parallel, is it that the final IV curve is the simple addition of voltages

No, when two devices (solar cells or anything else) are in parallel, the voltages are equal and the currents add.

> Also can you answer the same question for solar cells in series.

When two devices are in series, the voltages add.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I think I put my question incorrectly. Edited it and rephrased my question

Comment: @NikhilKumar, it doesn't change the answer: When the devices are in parallel, the currents add. When the devices are in series the voltages add.